# Eventbrite - Publish an event using using REST API

Tags: eventbrite

I am able to create an event using the REST API , but when I try to publish it using the API I am getting "*There are errors with your arguments: event.tickets - MISSING*" . Documentation says the tickets are required , But I don't see an option to pass the *event.tickets* in API ( I don't want to login to eventbrite and set the tickets after the event is created) . Thanks for your help.

**To create an event** ( Body parameters are given below )

https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/?token=mytokenid

```
  "event" : {
            "name": {
              "html": "Here is an event name"
            },
            "start": {
                "timezone": "America/Chicago",
                "utc": "2018-08-03T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "end": {
                "timezone": "America/Chicago",
                "utc": "2018-08-03T03:00:00Z"
            },
            "currency": "USD",
            "capacity":10
     }
```

**To publish the above event**( This is one throwing the error)

https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/99999999(eventid)/publish/?token=mytoken

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution for it , before publishing you have to call the tickets api to add the tickets ,

So here is the order to publish an event

1) Create event - https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/?token=mytoken

2) Add tickets to the above event  -  https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/aboveeventid/ticket_classes/?token=mytoken

3) Publish the above event - https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/aboveeventid/publish/?token=mytoken